# jQuery : $("#id") doesn't work in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've a problem with my jQuery function.

This code works:

```
$("input.read_picture").on('keyup', function () {
        $("#load_picture").attr('src', $(this).val());

        $("#load_picture").error(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.rnc-ci.net/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg');
        });

        $("#show_picture").css('display', 'block');
    });
```

But when I want to store my function not into my jQuery event, it doesn't work. Nothing displays.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
function changePicture(url) {
        $("#load_picture").attr('src', url);

        $("#load_picture").error(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.rnc-ci.net/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg');
        });

        $("#show_picture").css('display', 'block');
    }

    $("input.read_picture").on('keyup', changePicture($(this).val()));
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This,

```
$("input.read_picture").on('keyup', changePicture($(this).val()));
```

will call the function as soon as handler is loaded.

Use a callback,

```
$("input.read_picture").on('keyup', function(){
    changePicture($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> `jQuery` `.on` handler expects function as a second argument. You are invoking function, not passing it as argument. Invoked function does not return anything hence `undefined` is being passed as `handler` function.

Instead of calling a function, just pass function name which hold function definition. You can access value in the function body as `this.value` or `$(this).val()` as `this` refers to `DOM-Element` on which event is invoked.

```js
function changePicture() {
  var url = this.value;
  $("#load_picture").attr('src', url);
  $("#load_picture").error(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.rnc-ci.net/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg');
  });
  $("#show_picture").css('display', 'block');
}

$("input.read_picture").on('keyup', changePicture);
```

*Or with your current implementation, `changePicure` must return a function to be invoked as a handler function for `keyup`*

```js
function changePicture(url) {
  return function() {
    $("#load_picture").attr('src', url);
    $("#load_picture").error(function() {
      $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.rnc-ci.net/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg');
    });
    $("#show_picture").css('display', 'block');
  };
}

$("input.read_picture").on('keyup', changePicture('ANY_VALUE AS $(this).val() will not wors due to invalid context of this'));
```